# Kerning issue with luatex, Libertinus Serif, Source Code Pro fonts

Tags: luatex, kerning

With lualatex (version 0.95.0) I see incorrect kerning for the "tt" ligature when using "Source Code Pro" in conjunction with "Libertinus Sans" fonts:

[image: Incorrect kerning]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Libertinus Serif}
\setmonofont{Source Code Pro}
\begin{document}
foo \texttt{foo} twitter.
\end{document}
```

The same file results in correct output with xelatex on the same machine. I don't know enough about OpenType fonts to determine whether this is a bug in one of the fonts or in LuaTex itself.

The Source Code Pro font is from https://github.com/adobe-fonts/source-code-pro and Libertinus Serif from https://github.com/khaledhosny/libertinus.

Comment: Seems like a bug, possibly in luaotfload, but also Libertinus Serif is relevant; it doesn't happen with Linux Libertine O

Comment: Update to the latest release of SourceCodePro: https://github.com/adobe-fonts/source-code-pro/archive/2.030R-ro/1.050R-it.tar.gz and don’t forget to erase the cache.

Comment: Philipp Gesang's above comment solves the problem. Just today, I tried the OP's example, and was able to duplicate the problem under a variety of circumstances, using a fresh installation of Source Code Pro, but not the one in Philipp's link. When I downloaded the linked files, installed and refreshed cache, the problem disappeared.

Comment: After digging a little, this does indeed fix my problem, thanks. It didn't seem to initially, because I installed the new font version in ~/.fonts (and "fc-list" showed the font being picked up from there), but I also have a TeXLive version installed under texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/adobe/sourcecodepro which is the version picked up by luaotfload. So it's confusing for luaotfload to search differently from the fontcache tools, but that's another issue.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as solved in comments